# Date as input in Ksh on Solaris

Tags: ksh, sunos

I am on SunOS and trying to write a shell script which will take mins as input and display the final output as date in a particular format.

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
tm=$1
echo $(gdate -d"+$tm mins")ZZ
```

Save the above as t1.ksh and using 30 mins as input.

```
t1.ksh 30
Output : Wed Mar 28 17:41:04 CDT 2018

How can I get the output as **03-28-2017 5:41:04 PM**
```

Thanks

Comment: Add a format string to the gdate command `gdate -d"+$tm mins" "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" `.  Why use a `echo`, gda?e is already printing to stdout?

Comment: Yes, the solution worked. Thanks